# Trigger to copy data from a view to a table - T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, view, triggers

I'm wondering if there is any way to copy data from a view to a table in the same database. To be more clear, I have a view called AUTHORS_VIEW and a table called AUTHORS_TABLE. AUTHORS_VIEW takes data from others table in others databases.

I would copy new records in AUTHORS_VIEW not yet existing in AUTHORS_TABLE, update records in AUTHORS_VIEW not yet updated in AUTHORS_TABLE and remove record flagged as Removed in AUTHORS_VIEW from AUTHORS_TABLE.

Is it possible to achieve this with a trigger or others tool? I'm newbie with SQL Server.

This is my AUTHORS_VIEW (AUTHORS_TABLE is identical):

[image]

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to *store* that which can be calculated. Doing so *introduces* the opportunity for discrepancies. Why does the `AUTHORS_TABLE` exist at all if the data can already be computed by `AUTHORS_VIEW`?

Comment: This sounds like a bit of an antipattern - there should be a single "source of truth" for this data, and if you need to replicate it, then mirror it into identical tables in the target database.

Comment: Having said that, it sounds like some latency is allowable so just have a job schedulled that either truncates and re-inserts or inserts where not exists from the view.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. Unfortunatly latency is not allowed, so I think there is no solution for the problem to do it in a real-time, right?

Comment: I would do it to speed up queries, because the VIEW can contains so much data and can't be indexed. So I would like to have an internal table with indexes and stuff to make it more faster.

Comment: Do these other databases reside on the same server? If so just index the base tables appropriately and create a view that references just the required data.

Comment: A view can sometimes be indexed subject to some rules. If you [edit] and add your view we can see